# Custom error messages with reqparse of flask-restplus (V 0.12.1)

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have been following the flask-restplus [documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html).

How to return only the message specified in the "help" parameter of the add_argument function.

When the error is raised, the string in the "help" parameter is spitted out but with another appended string.

## Below is the code

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, reqparse

class Auth(Resource):
""" User signup and login """

    def post(self):
        """ signup """  
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str, required=True, 
         help="Username is required")   
        args = parser.parse_args() 
        return {"return": "sign up page"}


  ## This is the expected result
{
    "errors": {
        "username": "Username is required"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}

## Received result
{
    "errors": {
        "username": "Username is required Missing required 
parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}

#### I want to return the error message under "username" with only 
the message specified the "help"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask-restplus to parse fields, he help you with validation. Some links:

- https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html
- https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/reqparse.html#error-handling

In your code, `parser = reqparse.RequestParser()`, change to `parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)`.